# Python: Access "field" in line

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, string-comparison

I have the following .txt-File (modified bash emboss-dreg report, the original report has seqtable format):

```
Start     End  Strand Pattern                                                     Sequence

  43392   43420       + regex:[T][G][A][TC][C][CTG]\D{15,17}[CA][G][T][AT][AT][CTA] TGATCGCACGCCGAATGGAAACACGTTTT

  52037   52064       + regex:[T][G][A][TC][C][CTG]\D{15,17}[CA][G][T][AT][AT][CTA] TGACCCTGCTTGGCGATCCCGGCGTTTC

 188334  188360       + regex:[T][G][A][TC][C][CTG]\D{15,17}[CA][G][T][AT][AT][CTA] TGATCGCGCAACTGCAGCGGGAGTTAC
```

**I would like to access the elements under "sequence" only, to compare them with some variables and delete the whole lines, if the comparison does not give the desired result (using Levenshtein distance for comparison).**

But I can't even get started .... :(

I am searching for something like the linux -f option, to directly get to the right "field" in the line to do my comparison.

I came across re.split:

```
with open(textFile) as f:
    for line in f:
        cleaned=re.split(r'\t',line)
        print(cleaned)
```

which results in:

```
['  Start     End  Strand Pattern                                                     Sequence\n']
['\n']
['  43392   43420       + regex:[T][G][A][TC][C][CTG]\\D{15,17}[CA][G][T][AT][AT][CTA] TGATCGCACGCCGAATGGAAACACGTTTT\n']
['\n']
['  52037   52064       + regex:[T][G][A][TC][C][CTG]\\D{15,17}[CA][G][T][AT][AT][CTA] TGACCCTGCTTGGCGATCCCGGCGTTTC\n']
['\n']
[' 188334  188360       + regex:[T][G][A][TC][C][CTG]\\D{15,17}[CA][G][T][AT][AT][CTA] TGATCGCGCAACTGCAGCGGGAGTTAC\n']
['\n']
```

That is the closest I got to "split my lines into elements". I feel like totally going the wrong way, but searching Stack Overflow and google did not result in anything :(

I have never worked with seqtable-format before, so I tried to deal with it as .txt Maybe, there is another approach better for dealing with it?

Python is the main language I am learning, I am not so firm in Bash, but bash-answers for dealing with the issue would be ok for me, too.

I am thankful for any hint/link/help :)

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit.  You have received an answer and accepted it. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: The relation to `bash -f` is extremely tenuous at best. The talk about "maps" is similarly unclear to me. Perhaps avoid terminology and explain what you really mean until you have a solid grasp of the concepts.

Comment: I was searching for something like bash -f and I think the answer provided with the map is somehow like it? instead of having the field, there is the header I can use to get the "field". I don't know how to make my question clearer, but I cleared the tags

Comment: okay, I did not know, that I cannot comment/update after accepting an answer. I will keep that in mind for future questions, thank you

Comment: The Bash option `-f` disables wildcard expansion. I have no idea how it relates to the question here. Or if you mean `test -f` which checks for existence of a file, I can't see how that would be pertinent here, either.

Comment: I am not firm in bash, just checked an old script, I think, my memory was not precise, I think I meant the option f of cut. I used cut -f 1 to get the first part (="field") of a string in bash. I thought, there might be something similar in python, which grants "easy" access to a "field" in a line

Comment: but as I said, tags and header are cleaned, since they where indeed, missleading

Comment: The options of `cut` are different from the options of `bash` (and `test`, and `grep`, and the Linux kernel, etc). You can get the third field with `"string with spaces".split()[2]` (it's 2 and not 3 because Python array indices start at 0).

Comment: so, misleading was  to say "bash -f" instead of "bash cut -f"? (so I make it right in the future :)  )

Comment: Right, the options accepted by `cut` are independent on which shell you are using to run `cut` and indeed remain the same even if you don't have a shell at all (which is not feasible for interactive use, but very much a possibility e.g. with Python's `subprocess` module).

Comment: alright thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format itself seems to be using multiple lines as delimiters while your `r'\t'` is not doing anything (you're instructing Python to split on a literal `\t`). Also, based on what you've pasted the data is not using a tab delimiter anyway, but a random number of whitespaces to pad the table.

To address both, you can read the file, treat the first line as a header (if you need it), then read the rest line by line, strip the trailing\leading whitespace, check if there is any data there and if there is - further split it on whitespace to get to your line elements:

```
with open("your_data", "r") as f:
    header = f.readline().split()  # read the first line as a header
    for line in f:  # read the rest of the file line-by-line
        line = line.strip()  # first clear out the whitespace
        if line:  # check if there is any content left or is it an empty line
            elements = line.split()  # split the data on whitespace to get your elements
            print(elements[-1])  # print the last element
```

```
TGATCGCACGCCGAATGGAAACACGTTTT
TGACCCTGCTTGGCGATCCCGGCGTTTC
TGATCGCGCAACTGCAGCGGGAGTTAC
```

As a bonus, since you have the header, you can turn it into a map and then use 'proxied' named access to get the element you're looking for so you don't need to worry about the element position:

```
with open("your_data", "r") as f:
    # read the header and turn it into a value:index map
    header = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(f.readline().split())}
    for line in f:  # read the rest of the file line-by-line
        line = line.strip()  # first clear out the whitespace
        if line:  # check if there is any content left or is it an empty line
            elements = line.split()
            print(elements[header["Sequence"]])  # print the Sequence element
```

You can also use a header map to turn your rows into `dict` structures for even easier access.

**UPDATE**: Here's how to create a header map and then use it to build a `dict` out of your lines:

```
with open("your_data", "r") as f:
    # read the header and turn it into an index:value map
    header = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(f.readline().split())}
    for line in f:  # read the rest of the file line-by-line
        line = line.strip()  # first clear out the whitespace
        if line:  # check if there is any content left or is it an empty line
            # split the line, iterate over it and use the header map to create a dict
            row = {header[i]: v for i, v in enumerate(line.split())}
            print(row["Sequence"])  # ... or you can append it to a list for later use
```

As for how to 'delete' lines that you don't want for some reason, you'll have to create a temporary file, loop through your original file, compare your values, write the ones that you want to keep into the temporary file, delete the original file and finally rename the temporary file to match your original file, something like:

```
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

SOURCE_FILE = "your_data"  # path to the original file to process

def compare_func(seq):  # a simple comparison function for our sequence
    return not seq.endswith("TC")  # use Levenshtein distance or whatever you want instead

# open a temporary file for writing and our source file for reading
with NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False) as t, open(SOURCE_FILE, "r") as f:
    header_line = f.readline()  # read the header
    t.write(header_line)  # write the header immediately to the temporary file
    header = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(header_line.split())}  # create a header map
    last_line = ""  # a var to store the whitespace to keep the same format
    for line in f:  # read the rest of the file line-by-line
        row = line.strip()  # first clear out the whitespace
        if row:  # check if there is any content left or is it an empty line
            elements = row.split()  # split the row into elements
            # now lets call our comparison function
            if compare_func(elements[header["Sequence"]]):  # keep the line if True
                t.write(last_line)  # write down the last whitespace to the temporary file
                t.write(line)  # write down the current line to the temporary file
        else:
            last_line = line  # store the whitespace for later use
shutil.move(t.name, SOURCE_FILE)  # finally, overwrite the source with the temporary file
```

This will produce the same file sans the second row from your example since its sequence ends in a `TC` and our `comp_function()` returns `False` in that case.

For a bit less complexity, instead of using temporary files you can load your whole source file into the working memory and then just overwrite it, but that would work only for files that can fit your working memory while the above approach can work with files as large as your free storage space.

Comment: thank you. I think, I went to my goal to fast and stupidly ignored the structure of my input. I have not used maps often, but I used dictionaries already (and quite liked them). I now can try to do the dictionary part on my own :)

Comment: somehow, my research on header maps is not very successfull. Could you provide a detailed notation of your header=.... part? I think I am not the best in understanding this way of "short form". Thanks in advance!

Comment: the reason I am asking is, that I thought of using the map directly. My final aim is to delete entries, where the sequence part is more than 2 away from a pattern I compare to (Levenshtein). See update of the code. But when searching for how to delete an entry in a map, I could not find anything :(

Comment: If you are asking how to use `map()` to delete something, you can't do that.  The friend of `map()` is `filter()` which can do exactly that.

Comment: @zwer thank you for the update! I learned a lot so far. The reason, why I want to delete entries is, that my analysis has a biological background. I search for motifs in a genome. My first result is allowing all biologically logic permutations of the motif. For a second result, I need to limit the permutations, allowing only 4 letters of the total motif to be different from the "best match". Furthermore, the 4 letters need to appear at certain positions (2 in the beginning, two in the end, the middle of my motif-sequence is not considered). I learned a lot thanks to your answer :)